# Refactoring - Simplifying nested for loops in java

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, refactoring

I need to figure out how to improve following code:

```
      for (DirCategory c1 : categories1) {
            c1.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c1));
            log.debug("c1: "+c1.getCount()+" - "+c1.getName());
            dirCategoryService.persist(c1);

            List<DirCategory> categories2 = c1.getChildren();
            for (DirCategory c2 : categories2) {
                c2.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c2));
                log.debug("  c2: "+c2.getCount()+" - "+c2.getName());
                dirCategoryService.persist(c2);

                List<DirCategory> categories3 = c2.getChildren();
                for (DirCategory c3 : categories3) {
                    c3.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c3));
                    log.debug("    c3: "+c3.getCount()+" - "+c3.getName());
                    dirCategoryService.persist(c3);

                    List<DirCategory> categories4 = c3.getChildren();
                    for (DirCategory c4 : categories4) {
                        c4.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c4));
                        log.debug("      c4: "+c4.getCount()+" - "+c4.getName());
                        dirCategoryService.persist(c4);

                        List<DirCategory> categories5 = c4.getChildren();
                        for (DirCategory c5 : categories5) {
                            c5.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c5));
                            log.debug("        c5: "+c5.getCount()+" - "+c5.getName());
                            dirCategoryService.persist(c5);

                            List<DirCategory> categories6 = c5.getChildren();
                            for (DirCategory c6 : categories6) {
                                 c6.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c6));
                                log.debug("          c6: "+c6.getCount()+" - "+c6.getName());
                                 dirCategoryService.persist(c6);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would really appreciate any help simplifying this "thing"

Comment: OMG what a crazy code...

Comment: My brains are all over the wall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a great job for recursion, since all of the loops have exactly the same structure and content.  The recursive idea is to nest all the loops to some depth d, with the recursive structure being

- Nesting to depth zero is a no-op, and
- Nesting to depth d + 1 does a for loop over all loops of depth d.

This could be written as

```
private static void recursiveExplore(List<DirCategory> categories, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0) return;

    for (DirCategory c1 : categories) {
        c1.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c1));
        log.debug("c1: "+c1.getCount()+" - "+c1.getName());
        dirCategoryService.persist(c1);

        recursiveExplore(c1.getChildren(), depth - 1);
    }
}
public static void explore(List<DirCategory> categories) {
    recursiveExplore(categories, 5);
}
```

You can then do the exploration by calling `explore`.

Of course, this approach works with the assumption that the depth is at most five.  If you want to eliminate the depth requirement and just explore all the way down to the bottom of the directory, then you can just eliminate the depth parameter like this:

```
public static void explore(List<DirCategory> categories) {
    for (DirCategory c1 : categories) {
        c1.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c1));
        log.debug("c1: "+c1.getCount()+" - "+c1.getName());
        dirCategoryService.persist(c1);

        recursiveExplore(c1.getChildren(), depth - 1);
    }
}
```

More generally, any time you want to nest an arbitrary number of loops inside of one another, consider recursion as an option.  It's a very general framework for expressing this concept.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
void categoryPersister(DirCategory c){
    c.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c));
    log.debug("c: "+c.getCount()+" - "+c.getName());
    dirCategoryService.persist(c);
    for (DirCategory child : c.getChildren()) {
       categoryPersister(child) ;
    }
}
```

something like this.

Comment: One more thing. Since we don't know the depth of the structure, I think it would be better not to utilize call stack. Therefore we can reduce probability of `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @pavelrappo, true, should add some kind of "level counter" but it is aditional feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this recursively?  You should be able to nest this logic into a recursive call pretty nicely... You should be able to get some performance gains out of this as well.  Another advantage to doing it this way is that it won't matter how many levels your folders are nested.

[Wikipedia article on Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion.

```
void handleChild( List<DirCategory> catgories) {
     if(categories == null || categories.lenth() == 0) // not sure what the condition is
        return;
     else {
       for( DirCategory cat : catgories) {
         // do stuff
          handleChild(cat.getChild())
         }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta love recursion:

```
public void persist(DirCategory category, int level) {
    category.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(category));
    log.debug(level + ": "+category.getCount()+" - "+category.getName());
    dirCategoryService.persist(category);
    List<DirCategory> catChildren = cateogyr.getChildren();
    for (DirCategory child : catChildren) {
      persist(child, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Inside your code:

```
persist(c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write two methods:

1st for retrieving DirCategory, 2nd for retrieving children. Something like this:

```
private void retrieveDirCategory(DirCategory c) {
    c.setCount(dirEntryService.getDirEntryCategoryCount(c));
    log.debug("c: "+c.getCount()+" - "+c.getName());
    dirCategoryService.persist(c);      
}

private void retrieveDeep(Collections<DirCategory> categories, int deep) {
    if (deep == 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (DirCategory c : categories) {
        retrieveDirCategory(c);
        retrieveDeep(c.getChildren(), deep-1);
    }
}
// and you call:
// retrieveDeep(categories1, 6);
```